# Android Mediarecorder: Getting 3GP instead of MPEG4

Tags: java, android, audio-recording, video-recording

I want to record video only in android with MPEG4 format. I want the container and codec to be MPEG4. So here is what I have done for that.

```
Thread video = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        videoRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
        videoRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceView.getHolder().getSurface());
        videoRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.DEFAULT);
        videoRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
        videoRecorder.setVideoEncodingBitRate(56 * 8 * 1024);
        videoRecorder.setVideoSize(176, 144);
        videoRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(12);
        videoRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.MPEG_4_SP);
        videoRecorder.setOutputFile("/sdcard/video.m4e");
        try {
            videoRecorder.prepare();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        videoRecorder.start();
    }
});
video.start();
```

Now, after recording, I got the video recorded into `video.m4e` file. But when I check its information, I got the following:

[image]

At the same time I used the following to record audio:

```
Thread audio = new Thread(new Runnable() {              
    public void run() {
        audioRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
        audioRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        audioRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.RAW_AMR);
        audioRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
        audioRecorder.setOutputFile("/sdcard/audio.amr");
        try {
            audioRecorder.prepare();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        audioRecorder.start();
    }
});
audio.start();
```

and I got the container format and codec as AMR as I intended:

[image]

So, what causes `MediaRecorder` to record video in 3GP format? I haven't specified 3GP anywhere in my program. I am testing this code on my Samsung Galaxy tab running Android 2.2

Answer (score 7, accepted):

MPEG-4 is a method of defining compression of audio and visual (AV) digital data.
A file format for storing time-based media content. It is a general format forming the basis for a number of other more specific file formats (e.g. 3GP, Motion JPEG 2000, MPEG-4 Part 14).
So there is no conspiracy in the result you got, the compression method (OR "Codec") you used was MPEG4 and the video format generated by your phone is 3gp, which in actual is a part of the video formats of the suite of the MPEG4 compression scheme for the media.

Comment: Does that mean I can't record video in MPEG4 format with MPEG4 container?

Comment: you are again getting confused. Its in MPEG4 standard but in the 3gp format which in turn is the simplified format for the "mp4", specifically designed for the support for the mobile devices.

Comment: OK I got it now. Can I record raw video without putting inside a container?

Comment: i guess if you do that, some default compression scheme would be applied by the system itself. But I am not sure about this.

Answer (score 0):

This is defined by the frameworks. Specifically it has a set of parameters that are found in the MediaRecorder class that define what all is supported.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little bit more please?

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand akkilis's explanation.

In the official Android tutorial ["MediaRecorder.OutputFormat"](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.html), 
MPEG_4 is one of options of "media file formats", parallel to THREE_GPP. 
int     AAC_ADTS    AAC ADTS file format
int     AMR_NB  AMR NB file format
int     AMR_WB  AMR WB file format
int     DEFAULT
int     MPEG_4  MPEG4 media file format
int     RAW_AMR     This constant was deprecated in API level 16. Deprecated in favor of MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AMR_NB
int     THREE_GPP   3GPP media file format

There is another parameter to specify the encoding format:
["MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder"](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.html)

int     DEFAULT
int     H263
int     H264
int     MPEG_4_SP

In OP's code, he specified both file format and encoding format.

> videoRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
>   videoRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.MPEG_4_SP);

So it seems akkilis's explanation does not work for this example.